# Django issues passing variable from view to template javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

**Description:**

I have an view that is called every second to display temperature data to *temperature.html* from the backend of my project. In order for it to fulfill its purpose it needs an variable which will be passed through render to the template, where i want it to be used as an Javascript variable in order to update the canvas-gauge that I am using within the template to display temperature data.

---

**Problem:** 
My view is being called through the console at the correct interval, so that is not the issue. However, what is not happening is the variable is not being passed through to the template at all. I have tried to have the template display the variable to see if the variable is at least being sent to the template. Answer: It is not reaching the template at all, variable outputs *"undefined"*. I have passed forms in this manner through my other views in the same way I am attempting to pass this variable, and it works correctly. I do not understand where I am mistaken with my template/view. I have researched for at least 6 hours in attempt to find the solution and clearly I have not found an solution relevant to what I need. From what I've read it seems the way I am passing my variable is correct. However, I am relatively new to Django, so there are components to the matter that I don't quite understand yet.

---

**Relevant Code**
Partial snapshot of *Views.py*

```
def temperatureView(request):
    print("refresh..")
    #sen = Sensor()
    temperature = random.randint(1,100) #this is just an test variable
    print(temperature) #for debugging assistance

    return render(request,'temperature.html',{'Temperature':temperature})
```

---

Referenced *temperature.html*

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Mikhus/canvas-gauges/gh- 
pages/download/2.1.4/all/gauge.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "test">
</div>
<canvas data-type="radial-gauge"
            data-width="300"
            data-height="300"
            data-units="&deg F"
            data-title="Temperature"
            data-value="0"
            data-min-value="0"
            data-max-value="100"
            data-major-ticks="0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100"
            data-minor-ticks="2"
            data-stroke-ticks="false"
            data-highlights='[
              { "from": 0, "to": 50, "color": 
                "rgba(0,255,0,.15)" },
              { "from": 50, "to": 100, "color": 
                "rgba(255,255,0,.15)" },
              { "from": 100, "to": 150, "color": 
                "rgba(255,30,0,.25)" },
              { "from": 150, "to": 200, "color": 
                "rgba(255,0,225,.25)" },
              { "from": 200, "to": 220, "color": 
                "rgba(0,0,255,.25)" }
            ]'
            data-color-plate="#222"
            data-color-major-ticks="#f5f5f5"
            data-color-minor-ticks="#ddd"
            data-color-title="#fff"
            data-color-units="#ccc"
            data-color-numbers="#eee"
            data-color-needle-start="rgba(240, 128, 128, 1)"
            data-color-needle-end="rgba(255, 160, 122, .9)"
            data-value-box="true"
            data-animation-rule="bounce"
            data-animation-duration="500"
            data-font-value="Led"
            data-animated-value="true"
></canvas>
<script>
   var gaugeElement = 
   document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
   var Current_Temperature = {{Temperature}} 
   <!-- Where I want passed variable to go -->
   document.write(Current_Temperature);
   gaugeElement.setAttribute('data-value', Current_Temperature) 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT:** I thought I'd better go ahead and add the other view and template this corresponds to.

Another snippet of *Views.py*

```
def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

*Home.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <title>Incubator Status Page</title>
   <head>
    {% load static %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Mikhus/canvas-gauges/gh- 
     pages/download/2.1.4/radial/gauge.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'canvas-gauges-master/gauge.min.js' %}"> 
    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
     scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" 
           href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
            family=Lato">
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
             href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
                   awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <style>

       .incubatorTitle{
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 40px;
        }
       .incubatorVersion{
          text-align: center;
        }
       .test-button {
          border-radius: 4px;
          background-color: #f4511e;
          border: none;
          color: #FFFFFF;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 28px;
          padding: 10px;
          width: 200px;
          height: 50px;
          transition: all 0.5s;
          cursor: pointer;
          }
         .test-button:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}
         .test-button:after {
           background-color: #3e8e41;
           box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
           transform: translateY(4px);
          }
         .button-space{
            margin:50px;
          }
         .content{
             margin-left: 200px;
             margin-right: 200px;
             width: 1500px;
             height: 3000px;
             background-color: red;
          }
        .temperature{
             position: fixed;
             bottom:0px;
             left:200px;
             height:300;
             width:300;
          }
         .humidity{
             position: fixed;
             bottom:0px;
             right:200px;
             height:300;
             width:300;
          }
         .hatch{
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             background-size: 200px;
             position: fixed;
             text-align: center;
             top: 50px;
             right: 200px;
             width: 500px;
             height: 200px;
             border-color: yellow;
             border-width: 5px;
             border-style: solid;
             font-size: 20px;
             }
          .turn{
               background-repeat: no-repeat;
               background-size: 200px;
               position: fixed;
               text-align: center;
               top: 50px;
               left: 200px;
               width: 500px;
               height: 200px;
               border-color: yellow;
               border-width: 5px;
               border-style: solid;
               font-size: 20px;
               }

</style>
</body>
<body>

<div class="w3-top">
  <div class="w3-bar w3-black w3-card">
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-medium 
      w3-hide-large w3-right" href="javascript:void(0)" 
      onclick="myFunction()" 
      title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
        <h class = w3-bar w3-bar-title>Incubator Status Page</h6>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3- 
           padding-large">Status</a>
    <a href="{% url 'IncubatorProgramming' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3- 
       button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">Program Your 
       Incubator</a>
    <a href="{% url 'IncubatorSettingsPage' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3- 
       button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">Settings</a>
    <a href="{% url 'IncubatorHelpPage' %}" class="w3-bar-item w3- 
       button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">Help</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id = "main" class = "content" >
<div class="hatch">
<p id="hatchTimer"></p>
    Time until Hatch
<script>
    var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

    var x = setInterval(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "~/pythoncode.py",
        data: { param: text}
        }).done(function( o ) {
                {{InterfaceObject}}
            });
}, 1000);
</script>

</div>


<h1 class="incubatorTitle">Incubator Monitoring System</h1>
<h6 class = "incubatorVersion">Version 0.76</h6>
<div id = "temperaturRefreshable" class="temperature">
   {% include 'temperature.html' %}</div>
   <script>
   function temperatureDiv(){
    $.ajax({
   url: 'IncubatorTemperature',
   success: function() {
   $('temperaturRefreshable').html();
      setTimeout(temperatureDiv,1000);
   }
 });
    }
     // This reloads the <div> every 1 second.
    $(function(){
        temperatureDiv();
    });
</script>

<div class="humidity">
   <!-- this will get another guage as well -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you look at temperature.html source in your browser's dev tools, what do you see on the line `var Current_Temperature = ...`?

Comment: How is this being called every second?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I replicated your code in a cloud playground: https://cloud-playground.appspot.com/playground/p/5784640695566336/#hello%2Ftemplates%2Ftemperature.html and it works ok. The problem must be elsewhere. Could you have a view that conflicts with this one? Other javascript that is intefering?

Comment: And fwiw your cdn gauge js include is a 404: cdn.rawgit.com/Mikhus/canvas-gauges/gh- 
pages/download/2.1.4/all/gauge.min.js

Comment: @dirkgroten it prints out "undefined"

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is repeated in an different template where the view is called. I think I'll go ahead and add that.

Comment: You've misunderstood what dirkgroten asked. The line `var Current_Temperature...` in the rendered HTML won't say 'undefined', although you might get that in the console. What *does* it say in the HTML?

Comment: @EricConner Oh no, my guage loads perfectly fine, that's not the issue. The issue is updating Current_Temperature with the variable I'm trying to pass through. I'm surprised you're getting an 404 on the cdn, no issues here on that front.

Comment: Why won't you answer the question about what is rendered on that line?

Comment: @DanielRoseman dirkgroten I've looked over the dev tools. I noticed somehow that I forgot an semicolon in that call. Upon adding it i'm getting an exception, the page doesn't seem to think that the {{Temperature}} exists.

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry it's the first time I've used dev tools. Needed to look up the info.

Comment: @EricConner I doubt there is an conflicting view. Although it is called within the home view in an dedicated div, since it needs to update at an different rate than the rest of the page.

Comment: @DanielRoseman found this on that line just now message
:
"Current_Temperature is not defined"
stack
:
"ReferenceError: Current_Temperature is not defined↵    at eval (eval at b (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:25741), <anonymous>:1:1)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.b (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:25741)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like you're trying to call your temperature view over ajax to update your home view.

There are a couple of problems here. In Django, the templates are rendered server side before they're loaded on the client's browser. When you call

```
{% include 'temperature.html' %}
```

You're just including temperature.html and passing no variables so `Temperature` will be undefined since this is rendered only once *server side*.

To actually get an updating value, you should take the result of your ajax request and then write it to the document.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'IncubatorTemperature',
   success: function(data) {
     $('#temperaturRefreshable').html(data);
     setTimeout(temperatureDiv,1000);
   }
});
```

Here is a minimal working example that is close to what you want:
https://files.fm/u/tknysjks

Edit: 
Changed to a better download link: https://files.fm/u/tknysjks

Comment: I fixed the ajax bit. So to get the contents of temperature.html I do that without the include right? Also I tried to go to your link also, it says acess denied.

Comment: Yes, without the include. Oh, weird, on cloud playground it says the project is public. Here's a link to a zip of the sample project: https://files.fm/u/tknysjks

Comment: Ok I think I see what's going on here now. Thanks for the help!